# About eigenvalues of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator in the space of polynomials of degree less or equal to n, $T(p(x))=xp´(x)$. I need to calculate the eigenvalues of this operator.

So far, I calculated the matrix of the transformation in the canonical basis:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 &...  &0  \\
         &   &   & ... &  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 &...  &n  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

And if I calculate the characteristic polynomial of this matrix, then $0,1,2,3,...,n$ are all eigenvalues. I don´t know how to calculate the associated eigenspace for EACH of these values. Am I missing something? Thak you!

Comment: So, just to recap: you found a basis composed of eigenvectors of $T$, correct?

Comment: Not quite. I don´t know the English word of it. In Spanish we call it canonical basis, is the basis of the space of polinomials ${1,x,x^2,...,x^n}$ It think that those are in fact eigenvectors, but I was not thinking of that...

Comment: Standard basis, I think. Regardless, you've got it! (and the way you could've seen it is the representing matrix was diagonal.)

Comment: That's right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For that matrix, an eigenvector for the $i$'th diagonal eigenvalue is $E_{i}$, where this is the vector with the $i$'th entry $1$ and all other entries $0$.

It looks like in your case all eigenvalues are distinct, and hence each eigenspace is $1$ dimensional and generated by each eigenvector we found.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of that, I just didn't know how to write it down.